# how to add up a char array (and make them change into integer)

Tags: c++

now have a char array like

```
char a[5]={1,2,3,4,5}
```

but how to add them up?
I try this

```
int sum=0
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)sum = sum + a[i];
cout<<sum;
```

but it is wrong.
why?

Comment: remove the possibility for error and use `std::accumulate` (from `<numeric>`) with `std::begin` and `std::end` functions.

Comment: Can you explain what's "wrong" about your code (apart from only adding the first four elements of a five-element array)?  Show us a [mcve] and the actual and expected output, if you want to attract good answers to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop must go to 5 so that the indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
```

Besides that you are missing `;` in the end of two lines.

So the whole code:

```
char a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};  // added ;
int sum=0;              // added ;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)sum = sum + a[i];  // Changed 4 to 5
cout<<sum;
```

will print `15`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not looping enough times and missing the final item. That is already established in another answer.

There are mechanisms in c++ to avoid such out by one errors (one of the most common types).

Take these two examples that do not require to explicitly state how many elements are in the collection you are iterating over.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    /*
        #1 use range based for loop
    */
    int t = 0;
    for(char c: a) 
        t += c;
    std::cout << t << '\n';

    /*
        #2 use implicit loop in accumulate algorithm
    */
    int i = std::accumulate(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 0);
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

These are two idiomatic ways to write c++ and should eliminate a large number of simple errors from your code.